# Keep encrypted drive open after key is removed from system

Tags: 18.04, encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I have an encrypted drive that is mounted at boot time. I have three keys for the unit:

- Slot1: passphrase
- Slot2: file1
- Slot3: file2

For unattended boot (avoiding typing the passphrase), I have `file1` stored on a USB drive that I insert in the computer before I start the computer.

I want to remove the USB drive (just unplug) when the system is up and keep the encrypted drive open.

However, I only keep the drive open if I unmount properly the USB drive. If I just unplug the USB drive, the encrypted drive is "closed" again.

**/etc/fstab**

```
UUID=<UUID>  /mnt/usb  ext4  defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=1
/dev/mapper/cryptdrive  /mnt/cryptdrive  ext4  defaults,rw,nofail  0  0
```

Using an encrypted drive with Luks on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. In the post-MBR gap

If your *file1* is small enough you can squeeze it in the **post-MBR** gap after the MBR and before the start of the first partition, if using MBR of course.

It's a more technical challenge as you have to fiddle with `dd` command with correct `skip` and `bs` parameter.
You will also need to use the option **keyfile-offset** to specify the start of your file, like the other options below to `cryptsetup`.

So in details:

1. First check there is enough room to squeeze the file:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdx
   ```

Let call s, the start of the partition; then `s*512-512` should be more than the size of your key file, in bytes (assuming 512 bytes sector size)

At the very least, you can move the start of the partition with gparted for example.

2. Then copy your key file

   ```
   sudo dd if=/path/to/my/key/file1 of=/dev/sdx bs=1 seek=1024
   ```

I have used 1024 here but the MBR is only 512 bytes so if you are sure you can use 512

3. in `/etc/crypttab`

   ```
   cryptdrive UUID=<some UUID> /dev/disk/by-id/usb-_USB_DISK_2.0_11111111-0:0 luks,keyfile-offset=1024,keyfile-size=10222
   ```

Again, you need to adjust all the parameter:

- the keyfile-offset is what you used before, be it 1024 or 512 or whatever.
- the keyfile-size is the size of your key file in bytes
- and the id of your usb key that you can find in /dev/disk/by-id, once plugged in.

**Try this on a usb key with no important data, just in case something goes wrong or make backup.**

## 2. Raw partition

The **other solution** is to store the file inside a **raw partition** *not formatted* with a filesystem.

Say, you add a second partition to your usb key: `/dev/sdx2`

Then copy your file into that partition:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/my/key/file1 of=/dev/sdx2
```

You don't have to put anything in `/etc/fstab` to mount any filesystem because there isn't any.
It would be best to ensure no other partition is auto-mounted on that key too. You can use a `noauto` option in `/etc/fstab`

Just pass the partition directly to *cryptsetup* in `/etc/crypttab` with

```
cryptdrive UUID=<some UUID> /dev/disk/by-partuuid/<some-uuid> luks,keyfile-size=10222
```

if using *GPT*, else use id

```
cryptdrive UUID=<some UUID> /dev/disk/by-id/usb-_USB_DISK_2.0_11111111-0:0-part2 luks,keyfile-size=10222
```

You need to go and dig in `/dev/disk/by-id` to find the correct name for your partition. Don't use the `/dev/sdx2` name as it can change at any time to something else.

You have to specify the size of your file with the **keyfile-size** option (in bytes I guess)

Comment: Really good answer :-) I really like your proposal. I've chosen the second approach, but I want to try the first one, that seems looks better to me. Once the key is stored in the `post-MBR` space, how I define the entry in `/etc/crypttab`? just by UUID?

Comment: I will update my answer with that